# How to find the location of HTML element using javascript reliably

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html block that is consist of many `<div>`s. 
I use these `<div>`s to create modal windows by altering their opacity upon `target` (done in CSS). 
These `<div>`s are distinguished by `id` and all have the same class name. 
The `<div>`s have a border of **10px**. Upon mouse hover, the border is changed to **38px** for right and left border only (done in css).
Upon mouse hover I want to show back and next arrow to appear exactly middle of the left and right hand border. Different 'div's have different heights.

My approach: 
I have use the `event.target.id` to get the `id` of the `<div>` that calls the function. 
Then I used the `getBoundingClientRect()` to get a rectangle representation of that element on the screen.
I used the `.top` `.bottom` `.left` `.right` to get the x and y coordinates of each four points. From these points I find the height and then set the `<div>`s `.left` and `.right` to be equal to it.
I have used `alert(`) to return the result and it sometime returns the correct value and sometimes no values at all. The return result is either of these two. And the arrows don't get placed where they are suppose to. I am quite new to Javascript and I am still learning so I'd appreciate if you also explain your answers.
The HTML codes is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="midpointHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modalDialogHover.js"></script>
</head>

<!--first modal-->  
<a href="#X">
    <image src="X.gif" id="X" class="Gif" />
</a>
<div id="h" class="modalDialog">
 <div id="miniModal_h" class="miniModal" onmouseover="getMidPointHeight(event)">
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" id="close"><div class="close_btn"></div></a>
  <a href="#p" title="Next" class="next" id="next"><div class="next_btn"></div></a>                 
  <p>
     <!--some text here-->
  </p>                              
 </div>
</div>


<!--second modal-->     
<a href="#p">
<image src="p.gif" id="p" class="Gif" />
</a>
<div id="p" class="modalDialog">
    <div id="miniModal_p" class="miniModal" onmouseover="getMidPointHeight(event)">
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close"><div class="close_btn"></div></a>
        <a href="#h" title="Back" class="back" id="back"><div class="back_btn"></div></a>
        <a href="#c" title="Next" class="next" id="next"><div class="next_btn"></div></a>
        <p>
            <!--some text here-->
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

in CSS:

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999; 
    opacity: 0; 
}
.modalDialog > div {    
    width: 704px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    background: white;
    border-image: url("grey_flat_tile.png");
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
    border-image-slice: 30%;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.modalDialog:target{
    opacity:1;      
}
.next_btn { 
    display: none;          
    background-image: url("arrow_right.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 22px;
}
.back_btn{                      
    display: none;  
    background-image: url("arrow_left.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 22px;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

In jQuery to hid/show the left and right buttons on the panels:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".miniModal").hover(
        function(){
            jQuery(".close_btn").addClass("visible"),
            jQuery(".next_btn").addClass("visible"),
            jQuery(".back_btn").addClass("visible")
        },
        function(){
            jQuery(".close_btn").removeClass("visible"),
            jQuery(".next_btn").removeClass("visible"),
            jQuery(".back_btn").removeClass("visible")
        }
    )
});
```

In javascript to find the midpoint height and show the arrow at the right position:

```
function getMidPointHeight(event){

    var miniModal= event.target.id;
    //alert(miniModal);

    var smallRect = document.getElementById(event.target.id).getBoundingClientRect();

    var sX = smallRect.left;
    var sY = smallRect.top;
    var sW = smallRect.right;
    var sH = smallRect.bottom;

    //alert(sX + "," + sY + "," + sW + "," + sH);

    var sHeight = (sH - sY);

    var smidHeight = (sHeight / 2);
    var arrow_loc = (smidHeight)+"px";

    alert(arrow_loc);

    var next_btn = document.getElementById("next_btn");
    next_btn.style.top = arrow_loc;

    var back_btn = document.getElementById("back_btn"); 
    back_btn.style.top = arrow_loc; 
}
```

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: This whole problem sounds like it should be solved with pure CSS.

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle.net before, so I am not sure if I have got everything there correctly. But here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/dpc70er0/1/

Comment: Nit, there are a lot more Div's and I thought it maybe easier to have the formatting covered by javascript. But I was thinking if I couldn't fix this I have to just manually find the midpoints for each div.